# Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type "UIImage"

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm trying to check if there is an image by using the below if statement:

```
var profileImage = UIImage()


 @IBAction func submitAction(_ sender: Any) {


    if profileImage != 0 && nameTextField.text != nil {


    let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

    let profileImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.profileImage, 0.4)

    let profileImageRef = storageRef.child("ProfileImages/\(uid)/profileImage.jpg")
    profileImageRef.put(profileImageData!, metadata: nil) {
        metadata, error in

        if error != nil{

            print("error!")

        }
        else{

            let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()
            let username = self.nameTextField.text
            let user : [NSObject : AnyObject] = ["uid" as NSObject : uid! as AnyObject, "username" as NSObject : username! as AnyObject, "profileImageURL" as NSObject : downloadURL! as AnyObject]



            let childUpdates = ["Users/\(uid)/" : user]
            databaseRef.updateChildValues(childUpdates)

        }
        }
        }

    }
```

However it returns error:

'Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type "UIImage'

I've also tried replacing 0 with nil but this wouldn't work with a UIImage.

Comment: @EricAya I've updated the code to show clearly what I'm trying to do!

Comment: var profileImage = UIImage()

Comment: Now there's enough info. Someone will probably answer soon. Good luck. :)

Comment: Cheers @EricAya

Answer (score 2):

Define profileImage as an optional and then you can check if it has a value or not using a guard statement.

```
var profileImage:UIImage?
guard let profileImage = profileImage, let name = nameTextField.text else { return}
let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
...
```

Comment: In general, just because you check if a variable isn't `nil` doesn't mean it is safe to force unwrap it. Another thread could make it `nil` in between the time you check it and force-unwrap it.

Comment: Well, I assumed this is the only thread accessing the variables, but you are right, using a guard statement is always safer, so I updated my answer, thanks for the input.